# Problems acessing parameter from controller (collection_select)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using a `collection_select` to pass the param `product_id` from a view to the controller, but i'm having problems on acessing that value. The other parameters are fine. If i do something like `aux = params[:product_id]` it saves the value 0 instead of 1, that is the value that the controller receives as you can see in the request log. Any help would be appreciated!

PS: I think it may be related with the curly brackets you can see around the product_id param as you can see in the request log

```
<%= collection_select(:params, :product_id, Product.all, :id, :name, :prompt => true) %>



Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"hE4qrSZnI8LLy6sNzR2fkRxKZpFoOHZLun6Z/cIsHDxGcCaC+zVPLk1qYFhf6iuhbmsZX0us75FIiqJ7c06Mxw==",
 "params"=>{"product_id"=>"1"},
 "quantity"=>"1",
 "event_id"=>"5",
 "commit"=>"GO!",
 "method"=>"post"}
```

Comment: The curly brackets are because it's a hash, just like the entire thing is. Without seeing the actual code to save it's hard to help. It's simple enough to dump out the value in the controller itself, e.g., with a `pry` session or a log statement. Other things may affect what's being stored.

Comment: @DaveNewton i added the code part where i store the value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're sending a key `params` inside of the real `params`, to access your value do it like:

```
params[:params][:product_id]
```

or use:

`collection_select(:object, :product_id, Product.all, :id, :name, prompt: true)`

to get product_id in params